# Need an alternative solution to this oracle query?Without using (flag) variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Question:
Create a Doctor table (Docname, Qualification, Specialization, Working_shift). 
Use parameterized cursor to check the availability of doctors given the specialization
and working shift of the day to serve the patients

I am just learning databases so if the question may seem trivial i apologize for that.

Getting the desired output on inputting the values but i need an alternative way to solve the question without using flag variable (so that i could get the exception)...if i don't use the flag it prints the exception as well as the docname and qualification

I am using oracle(cursor in a normal pl/sql block) to execute this query.

Solution:

```
  --table creation

  create table doctor
  (
  docname varchar2(20),
  qualification varchar2(20),
  specialization varchar2(20),
  shift varchar2(20)
  )
```

my solution

```
declare
    cursor c1 (specialization varchar2,shift varchar2) is select docname,qualification      from doctor
    where specialization='&sp' and shift='&shift'
    sp doctor.specialization%type;
    shift doctor.shift%type;
    flag number(10);
begin
    flag:=0;
    for r1 in c1(sp,shift)
    loop
        if c1%found then
            flag:=1;
            dbms_output.put_line('Doctor is available');
            dbms_output.put_line('Docname: '||r1.docname);
            dbms_output.put_line('qualification: '||r1.qualification);
        else
            flag:=0;
        end if;
    end loop;
    if flag=0 then
         dbms_output.put_line('Invalid specialization/shift');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try given below code

```
declare
cursor c1 (specialization varchar2,shift varchar2)
is 
select docname,qualification      
from doctor
where specialization='&sp' 
and shift='&shift'
sp doctor.specialization%type;
shift doctor.shift%type;
flag number(10);

begin
flag:=0;
for r1 in c1(sp,shift)
loop
    if c1%found then
        flag:=1;
        dbms_output.put_line('Doctor is available');
        dbms_output.put_line('Docname: '||r1.docname);
        dbms_output.put_line('qualification: '||r1.qualification);
    else
        raise;
    end if;
end loop;
exception

when others then
dbms_output.put_line('Invalid specialization/shift');

end;
```

Comment: you can't `raise;` outside of an exception handler unless you specify what exception to raise.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to reset the flag within the loop, you already initialised it to `0` at the start of the procedure.
2. You dont need to check `c1%found` because you're inside the loop; *by definition* a record was found, otherwise it wouldn't go into your loop code.
3. Your cursor should use the variables provided, not the SQL*Plus substitution variables, e.g.:

   ```
   cursor c1 (specialization varchar2,shift varchar2) is
     select docname,qualification
     from doctor
     where doctor.specialization=c1.specialization
     and doctor.shift=c1.shift;
   ```

   If you don't want to have to use all those aliases, you can use a naming convention to distinguish between the different identifiers (shift vs shift), e.g.:

   ```
   cursor c1 (i_specialization varchar2, i_shift varchar2) is
     select docname,qualification
     from doctor
     where specialization=i_specialization
     and shift=i_shift;
   ```

   Note also, you missed a semicolon at the end of the query.

Finally:

If you change your loop as follows, it should work fine:

```
for r1 in c1(&sp,&shift)
loop
    flag:=1;
    dbms_output.put_line('Doctor is available');
    dbms_output.put_line('Docname: '||r1.docname);
    dbms_output.put_line('qualification: '||r1.qualification);
end loop;
```

Now, your last bit of code:

```
if flag=0 then
     dbms_output.put_line('Invalid specialization/shift');
end if;
```

will work fine - it will only execute if flag is still `0` (i.e. the query found no rows).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use parameters in "c1" cursor you do not need it...

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT  docname, qualification
        FROM    doctor
        WHERE   specialization = '&sp'
        AND     shift          = '&shift';

    TYPE c1_ntt IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
    l_c1  c1_ntt;
BEGIN
    OPEN  c1;
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_c1;
    CLOSE c1;

    IF l_c1.COUNT = 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid specialization/shift');
    END IF;

    FOR indx IN l_c1.FIRST..l_c1.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Doctor is available');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Docname: '       || l_c1(indx).docname);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('qualification: ' || l_c1(indx).qualification);
    END LOOP;
END;
```